# POST-ing XML in AngularJS

Tags: xml, angularjs, http, post

I've been looking for hours for some `angularjs` documentation that explains how to POST xml data using the `$http` object. Does angular simply not offer it with their `$http` object? The code:

```
$http({ 
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://10.0.0.123/PHP/itemsGet.php',
  data: '<searchKey id="whatever"/>',
  headers: { "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for the same thing, however I tried Skyler's solution and it did not work.
I changed the content type to 'application/xml' and it worked.
Here is the snippet:

```
$http({ 
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://10.0.0.123/PHP/itemsGet.php',
    data: '<searchKey id="whatever"/>',
    headers: { "Content-Type": 'application/xml' }
})
```

Comment: _"I tried Skyler's solution and it did not work. I changed the content type to 'application/xml' and it worked"_ Changing the content type to application/xml **IS** Skyler's solution.

Comment: ok, now I look like a crazy person because I posted my answer before Skyler changed the answer to xml

Comment: He didn't change it to xml. Unfortunately the posted code was the "before" code, but the solution has always been _"Seemed that application/xml made more sense"_

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The `Content-Type` is threw me for a while. Seemed that `application/xml` made more sense. Oh well, whatever works!

```
$http({ 
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://10.0.0.123/PHP/itemsGet.php',
    data: '<searchKey id="whatever"/>',
    headers: { "Content-Type": 'application/xml' }
})
```