# $.ajax post vs. $http.post

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, xmlhttprequest, angular-http

Would appreciate some light shed on the following issue. I need to do an HTTP Post with XML data in my AngularJS client. I was able to achieve that using $.ajax POST:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, tranStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Status: ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText + '. ' +
                  'Response: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
  }
});
```

However, I wasn't able to figure out how to do it using $http or $resource:

```
$http({
      url: url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: data,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/xml"}
    }).success(function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }).error(function (error) {
        alert(error);
});
```

Where url and data are something like that:

```
url: 'http://192.168.1.3:8900'
data: "<PARENT><CHILD_1>1</CHILD_1><CHILD_2>Two</CHILD_2></PARENT>"
```

I have reviewed this 
[from jquery $.ajax to angular $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131659/from-jquery-ajax-to-angular-http)

and this [Angularjs $http VS jquery $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860207/angularjs-http-vs-jquery-ajax/20862089#20862089)

> and didn't find any clarification to my dilemma. CORS is not an issue
>   as it's enabled in my browser (Chrome). With $http I simply get 
>   "angular.js:9814 OPTIONS http://192.168.1.3:8900/
>   net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". And it errors out right away. Could it be something to do with the port? Host url looks good in dev tools...

Any tip will be much appreciated!

EDIT: I've tried the content-type for $http before with no difference. I reviewed [POST-ing XML in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373756/post-ing-xml-in-angularjs) and the question is different from mine. I have plenty of other $resource as well as older $http calls throughout my app as well as CORS calls to cross-domain WebAPI and have a decent experience with angularjs. However, I have never posted XML - always json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST-ing XML in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373756/post-ing-xml-in-angularjs)

Comment: have you checked this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373756/post-ing-xml-in-angularjs?

Comment: @gyc - Thanks for replying, however this is no dup, my question is different. Pls see my edit. Still puzzled...