# $http html data sent as string converts to JSON

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I've been struggling to send a simple string using $http.post in angularjs to a service in java. In the string I'm sending xhtml template content to feed into a pdf service.

The service somehow sees the data sent as a JSON object instead of a string. e.g. if I want to send:

`"<?xml version="1.0"><html><body><div>something</div></body></html>"`

it converts the string sent to:

`{"<?xml version": "\"1.0\"><html><body><div>something</div></body></html>"}`.

I have tried setting the content-type and also overriding the default.transformRequest but so far unsuccessful.

Comment: what is the content type sent as?

Comment: Please show all relevant code related to sending. See [mcve] If you are sending just xml you need to adjust `$http` config

Comment: `{"<?xml version": "\"1.0\"><html><body><div>something</div></body></html>"}` --- what's that?

Comment: The content-type is sent as "application-json;charset=utf-8" @DanielA.White

Comment: that doesn't look like a JSON response. seems like a problem with your service.

Comment: `$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/print/pdf',
                data: testData
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log('Response from PDF', response);
            });`                                                                                                                 where testData is : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body><div></div></body></html>` @charlietfl

Comment: need to disable request data processing in the config for that request...see $http docs

Comment: @charlietfl how can I disable request data processing? Thank you for your help

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373756/post-ing-xml-in-angularjs

Comment: @charlietfl I tried the solution above, it is still changing the request data sent to json.

Comment: try adding this to config `transformRequest: angular.identity`